# reading a text file with no particular format in R

Tags: r

I would like to read a text file which has variable number of columns in R.
My text file looks like follows. I would like to read into a data frame where I can just access the individual lines as df[1](http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/LIWC2001_English.dic) for the first line, df[2] for the second line and so on.

```
a       09
abandon*        12      16      19      20      24
abort*  60      61      62
about   10
above   10      41      42
abrupt* 37
absolut*        26
abuse*  12      16      18
abusive 12      16      18
academi*        47      48
accept  08      12      13      15      20      22      39
accepta*        08      12      13      15
accepted        08      12      13      15      20      38
```

I have tried the following

```
read.table("myfile",header=T,sep=" ")
```

but this inserts tab characters.

I have also tried readLines

```
singleString = readLines("myfile")
```

but this too inserts \t characters.

**EDIT** : (Thanks to   Dominic Comtois for helping thus far, I have got it to work but still don't know what's going wrong)

1. Initially the words on the left and the numbers on the right were separate by tabs, not spaces. And so R wasn't able to read it correctly

   > df = read.table('filename',sep="|")
   >   df$V1 = as.character(df$V1)
   >   df[1,"V1"](http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/LIWC2001_English.dic) "a\t09"
2. So I replaced tabs with spaces in vi editor using the command
   :1,$s/\t/  /g
3. I was then able to read it in R using  df = read.table('filename',sep="|") but certain lines looked like this
   (Surprisingly, when I read the file now, a lot of the apostrophes are gone. The first word was spelt as **aren't**, not it's **arent**)

   > df[123,](http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/LIWC2001_English.dic) "**arent**  07  39\nargu  12  16  18  31  32\narm  60  61\narms  60  61\narmy  31\naround  10  41\narous  12  60  61\narrange  20\narrive  39  46\narrived  46\narrives  39  46\narriving  46\narrogan  12  16  18\narse  60  61  66\narses  66\narsehole  66\narter  60  61\narthr  60  61\nas  10\nasham  12  16\nashes  57  59\nask  27  29  31  32  39\nasked  27  29  31  32  38\nasking  27  29  31  32\nasks  27  29  31  32  39\nasleep  60  64\nass  60  61  66\nassault  12  16  18\nassembl  31\nasses  66\nasshole  66\nassociatio  47  49\nassum  20  21\nassur  12  13  15  26\nasthma  60  61\nat  10\nate  27  38  60  63\natop  10  41  42\nattachment  12  13  14\nattract  12  13\nauditorium  47  48\naugust  37\naunt  31  35\nautumn  37\naversi  12  16  17\navoid  12  16  20  24\nawake  60  64\naward  12  13  15  47  50\naware  20  22\naway  10\nawesome  12  13\nawful  12  16\nbabe  31  36\nbabies  31  36\nbaby  31  36\nbad  12  16\nband  31  51  55\nbank  56\nbar  60  63\nbarrier  20  24\nbars  60  63\nbaseball  47  48  51  53\nbases  20  21\nbasis  20  21\nbasketball  47  48  51  53\nbastard  12  16  18  66\nbath  51  52  60  65\nbe  40\nbeaten  12  16  18  47  50\nbeaut  12  13\nbecame  20  22  38\nbecause  20  21\nbecome  20  39\nbecomes  20  39\nbecoming  20\nbed  51  52  64\nbeen  38\nbeer  60  63\nbefore  10  37\nbeg  31  32  39\nbegan  37  38\nbegged  31  32  38\nbegging  31  32\nbegin  37  39\nbeginn  37\nbegins  37  39\nbegs  31  32  39\nbelieve  20  22  39\nbelieved  20  22  38\nbelieves  20  22  39\nbelieving  20  22\nbelly  60  61\nbelow  10  41  43\nbeneath  10  41  43\nbenefit  12  13  39\nbenefits  12  13  47  49\nbenign  12  13\nbeside  10  41\nbesides  45\nbest  12  13  15  47  50\nbet  25  39  56\nbets  25  39  56\nbetter  12  13  47  50\nbetting  25  56\nbetween  10  41\nbewilder  12  16  17\nbi  60  62\nbible  57  58\nbicyc  51  53\nbig  41\nbillion  11\nbinge  60  61  63\nbiology  47  48\nbitch  12  16  18  66\nbitter  12  16  18  27\nbladder  60  61\nblam  12  16  18  31  32\nbleed  60  61\nbless  12  13  57  58\nblock  20  24\nblood  60  61\nboard  47  49\nboarder  41\nbodi  60  61\nbody  60  61\nbold  12  13  15\nbone  60  61\nbonus  47  49\nboobs  60  61  62  66\nbook  47  48\nbore  12  16\nboring  12  16\nborrow  56\nboss  47  49\nbother  12  16\nbottom  41  43\nbought  38  56\nbowel  60  61\nboy  31  36\nboy  31  36"
4. So I wrote these to a new file as

   write.table(df[grep("\n",df$V1),"V1"],'newlines')
5. But since we are writing so many sets of lines, it puts "" after
   every set. So I searched and replaced the " characters with
   empty, essentially removing them
6. I then opened them using the original commamnd and it worked,
   everything was in it's separate line

   df = read.table('newlines',sep="|")
        df$V1 = as.character(df$V1)

I also opened the file after replacing tabs with spaces in a hex editor and did not see anything peculiar.
This is the part from one line before where the problem starts

```
area  41
aren't  07  39
argu  12  16  18  31  32
arm  60  61
```

Corresponding hex

```
61 72 65 61 20 20 34 31 0A 61 72 65 6E 27 74 20 20 30 37 20 20 33 39 0A 61 72 67 75 20 20 31 32 20 20 31 36 20 20 31 38 20 20 33 31 20 20 33 32 0A 61 72 6D 20 20 36 30 20 20 36 31
```

If anyone would like to access the file, it can be found at 
http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/LIWC2001_English.dic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to have the numbers considered as different "cells" or "fields", you can set `sep` as a character that is nowhere in your source file.

For instance:

```
df1 <- read.table("myfile",sep="|")
```

As for `header=TRUE`, this should be used only if your first line contains the names of your columns. If it's not the case, don't put it in. To skip the first line instead, just use `skip=1`.

Then you'll be able to access the individual lines with

```
df1[1,] # for first line
df1[2,] # for second line
        # and so on ...
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me yet. I still get tab characters, can you have a look below.
> df <- read.table("myfile",sep="|")
> df$V1  =as.character(df$V1)
> df[[1]][1]
[1] "a\t09"
> df[[1]][2]
[1] "abandon\t12\t16\t19\t20\t24"
> df[[1]][3]
[1] "abort\t60\t61\t62"
> df[[1]][4]
[1] "about\t10"

Comment: Oh well that only indicates that the tab characters are in your input file! Open it with a text editor and replace tabs by spaces... or try using `sep="\t"` to have your dataframe well organized, if number of tabs are consistent. Or try with `sep="\t"` and `fill=TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic Comtois. I used set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab to replaces tabs with spaces, and then it worked.
But we're using sep="|" as delimiter. So was the problem because read.table expects a space as the delimiter?

Comment: When you say "it worked", you mean you have a dataframe with only 1 column I presume? Yes, from `?read.table` : _If sep = "" (the default for read.table) the separator is ‘white space’, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns._

Comment: I notice that one of my lines looks like "heres  39  41  44\nhero  12  13  15\nhers  01  06  31  33\nherself 01  06  31  33\nhesitant  12  16  17  20  24  25\nhesitat 20  24  25

If I remove all the newlines, it of course doesn't work because of read.table. How do I get rid of these?

Comment: This is odd... maybe you have 2 types of line feed in your document? (Linux/Windows)? You could try copying and pasting the content in a new text document and try again.

Comment: , I have made an edit to the question. I've got it to work, but not sure what the problem is. Please have a look if you get some time.

Comment: Try adding `quote=""`. I got good results with `read.table("http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/LIWC2001_English.dic", header=FALSE, sep = "|", quote = "")`

Comment: This is great. Thanks. I also read up about quote and about R's behavior to expect a closing quote for every single quote it sees, and consider everything between the two to be one line. It also clearly explains why my string was going wrong at the first word containing a single quote like aren't and getting back on track at the next single quoted word only to go wrong again at the next single quoted word.
If you could add this an answer, I could accept it.